# Tailwind custom forms plugin not working with Svelte Rollup

Tags: svelte, rollup, tailwind-css

I have this rollup config:

```
...
import tailwind from "tailwindcss";

...

export default {
  ...
  plugins: [
    svelte({
      preprocess: sveltePreprocess({
        postcss: {
          plugins: [tailwind("./tailwind.config.js")],
        },
      }),
      compilerOptions: {
        // enable run-time checks when not in production
        dev: !production,
      },
    }),

    css({ output: "bundle.css" }),

    resolve({
      browser: true,
      dedupe: ["svelte"],
    }),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({
      sourceMap: !production,
      inlineSources: !production,
    }),

    !production && serve(),
    !production && livereload("public"),

    // If we're building for production (npm run build
    // instead of npm run dev), minify
    production && terser(),
  ],
  watch: {
    clearScreen: false,
  },
};
```

And this tailwind.config.js file:

```
const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

module.exports = {
  purge: {
    content: ["./src/**/*.svelte", "./public/**/*.html"],
    css: ["./public/**/*.css"],
    enabled: production, // disable purge in dev
  },
  darkMode: "class",
  theme: {
    customForms: (theme) => ({
      default: {
        "input, textarea": {
          "&::placeholder": {
            color: theme("colors.gray.400"),
          },
        },
      },
    }),
    ...
  },
  plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/forms")],
};
```

I have it running in a Docker container. Tailwind styles are applied fine by using a custom `TailwindCSS.svelte` component that is imported into `App.svelte` and then applied there.

However the form styling by the [this plugin](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-forms) is not working.

Anyone any ideas? Is this due to the rollup config?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using standard svelte template and want to use `@tailwindcss/forms`, please make sure you've cleaned up styles in `public/global.css` cause they override some `@tailwindcss/forms` setup.